# .htaccess redirect to subfolder does not work

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect to the "backend" or "frontend" directory using htaccess in the following project structure?:

I tried this code in .htaccess but it doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Change '/myproject/' if directory is renamed
RewriteBase /myproject/
# Change the '/myproject/' portion of the condition if directory is renamed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myproject/backend/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ backend/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ frontend/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my project structure:

```
 
        myproject/
                 frontend/
                 backend/
                 common/
                 upload/
                .htaccess
```

Please help me.